# Strcpy function in c

Tags: strcpy

Output is:Hello
Hello
As you can see the image Can someone tell why I am getting this output!
Destination is Capable of holding only one character then how it can print entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the core part of your code otherwise we can't help you.

However, keep in mind that in C there is no automatic memory allocation, garbage collector and string type (which is an array of characters instead).

`strcpy` copies the entire source string to the pointer specified as the destination and stops only when it finds the `NULL` or `\0` character regardless of how large the destination buffer is.

What happens is definitely a **buffer overflow**, the data following the destination buffer (of one byte) is overwritten, potentially causing program instability and data corruption.

Comment: Thanks . Now I understood the problem